# text shadow on external monitor

Tags: external-display

On a Acer travelmate 5730 I've connected an external monitor(Samsung Syncmaster 225mw) using a svga cable.

The problem is that on the external monitor, the image/text is displayed with shadows. Do you have any idea about how can I fix this problem?

TY

Comment: See http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/52762-3-shadow-monitor#t379322

Comment: this really fixes the problem, TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your cable for a better one and the problem will almost certainly go away.

Comment: It looks better but the shadow didn't disappear entirely. TY for your replay